# Copying thousands of files (filtered by name) to a specified folder

Tags: python, copy

I'm trying to run two operations:

1. Starting from a .txt file containing some IDs (which lead to a filename), checking if that file is within a folder;
2. If step 1) is true, copying the file from that folder to a specified folder.

The .txt file stores codes like these:

```
111081
112054
112051
112064
```

This is what I have tried:

```py
from glob import glob
from shutil import copyfile
import os

input = 'C:/Users/xxxx/ids.txt'
input_folder = 'C:/Users/xxxx/input/'
dest_folder = 'C:/Users/xxxx/output/'
with open(input) as f:
   for line in f:
       string = "fixed_prefix_" + str(line.strip()) + '.asc'
       if os.path.isfile(string):
            copyfile(string, dest_folder)
```

The `string` variable generates this (for example):

```py
print string
fixed_prefix_111081.asc
```

Then, I'm sure there is something else wrong with the searching and the copying of the file to the destination folder. The main problem is that I don't know how to search for the `fixed_prefix_111081.asc` file in the `input_folder`.

Comment: try `line.strip()` to remove end of line char(s)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks, I managed that issue. I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `copyfile` expects a filename as destination. Passing an existing directory is the case where it doesn't work. Using `copy` handles both cases (target directory or target file)
- the input file seems to be passed *without path*. You'd have to generate the full filename if you're not in `input_folder` or `os.path.isfile` will always be `False`

My fix proposal:

```
with open(input) as f:
   for line in f:
       string = "fixed_prefix_{}.asc".format(line.strip())
       fp_string = os.path.join(input_folder,string)
       if os.path.isfile(fp_string):
            copy(fp_string, dest_folder)
```

Comment: Thanks for the perfect solution and for the explanation, I learned something new!